# Android Screen Recording

Tags: java, android, screen-recording, android-mediaprojection

Is **MediaProjection** (Screen Recording)can be used to record a specific view for some time instead of whole screen?.

Comment: I recommend you delete this question because it is too generic and it will get more downvotes.

Answer (score 2):

> Can any one can tel me that is it possible to record a specific view instead of whole screen?

No, sorry. The media projection APIs only record the entire screen. Mostly, that is because they are designed to be used for recording apps other than our own, and we do not know the details of those other apps (e.g., identities of specific views).

Comment: Many thanks. But why you down vote my question? CommonsWare

Comment: @BasitAli: I did not downvote your question. I answered your question. Three other people, so far, have downvoted your question.

Comment: Thanks for the Answer @CommensWare

Comment: @CommonsWare Is there any changes with the new API releases so far ? Thanks in advance

Comment: @Reda: No, sorry.